# Knockout binding throws an error after one form posts and the post is initiated from another form?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, knockout.js

I have 2 forms performing Ajax posts with knockout bindings on the HTML components.When the Edit form is submitted the Add form throws a binding error and prevents form submit.

Both the forms submit completely fine and do get the data stored or edited. However, once the edit is performed on any field, the add form gets disrupted and provides a binding error.

```
 <div class="row" id="addNewOrderUnitFormDiv">


                @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "OrderUnit", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", @id = "addForm" }))
                {
                    <h1>Add New Order Unit</h1>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <label class="has-float-label">
                                    @*<input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" id="addName" maxlength="50" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>*@
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Name", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name), data_bind = "value: Name" })
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @*@Html.Submit("Submit")*@
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-action" value="Submit" id="submitAddOrderUnit" data-bind="click: function(){AddOrderUnit();}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                }


            </div>

            <div class="row" id="editOrderUnitFormDiv" data-bind="with:EditModel,visible: EditShow">


                @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "OrderUnit", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", @id = "editForm" }))
                {
                    <h1>Edit Order Unit</h1>
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:OrderUnitId" id="editId" />
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <label class="has-float-label">
                                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" id="editName" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @*@Html.Submit("Submit")*@
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-action" value="Submit" id="submitEditOrderUnit" data-bind="click: function(){$root.EditOrderUnit();}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

            </div>
```

```js
var orderUnitModel = function (parent, id, name) {
        var self = this;
        self.OrderUnitId = ko.observable(id);
        self.Name = ko.observable(name);
        self.EditShow = ko.observable(); 
        self.EditModel = ko.observable();

        self.Edit = function () {
            //$('#editOrderUnitFormDiv').show();
            parent.EditShow(!parent.EditShow());
            parent.EditModel(self);
        }
}
 var orderUnitViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.OrderUnitId = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.EditShow = ko.observable(false);
        self.orderUnits = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.EditModel = ko.observable();


        self.GetOrderUnits = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetOrderUnits","OrderUnit")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                data: {},
                success: function (response) {
                    self.orderUnits.removeAll();
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        self.orderUnits.push(new orderUnitModel(self, response[i].OrderUnitId, response[i].Name));
                    }
                    console.log(self.Name);
                }
            });
        }
        self.AddOrderUnit = function () {
           var rData = {
                Name: self.Name()
           }
            var orderUnit = JSON.stringify(rData);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Add","OrderUnit")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: orderUnit,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#addForm').hide();
                    if (response.success == true) {
                        self.GetOrderUnits();
                        alert("Added Successfully");
                        //toastr.success("The Service was successfully added.");
                    } else {
                        alert("Not Added")
                        //toastr.error("The Service was not added.");
                    }
                    $('#addNewOrderUnit').on("click", function () {
                        $('#addForm')[0].reset();
                        $('#addForm').show();
                    })

                }
            });
        }

        self.EditOrderUnit = function () {
            self.OrderUnitId = $('#editId').val();
            self.Name = $('#editName').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit","OrderUnit")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(self),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        self.GetOrderUnits();
                        $('#editForm').hide();                       
                        alert("Edit Worked");
                        //toastr.success('The service was edited successfully.');
                    } else {
                        alert("Edit did not work");
                        //toastr.error('The service was not edited.');
                    }

                }
            });
        }
}
```

So once the edit is performed and it goes through, than while trying to add a new orderunit this error results:
`Index:249 Uncaught TypeError: self.Name is not a function
    at orderUnitViewModel.self.AddOrderUnit (Index:249)
    at orderUnitViewModel.eval (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-min.js:74), <anonymous>:3:76)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (knockout-min.js:100)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)`

However,if the add is performed irrespective of the Edit, it goes through. Or even when the page is refreshed, the add works fine.
I expect the add to work flawless after the edit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the code for `self.GetOrderUnits`? Since it is called when the edit has been performed, I would suspect this function does something that breaks your view model.

Comment: You are overwriting the observable inside `EditOrderUnit` method and turning it into a string: `self.Name = $('#editName').val()`. But, it seems like you are not using two-way bindings correctly. Why are you using jquery to get the value and assigning it to `self.Name`? You are already data-binding `Name` and `OrderUnitId ` to the inputs.

Comment: @BrotherWoodrow posted it, but I doubt that GetOrderUnit breaks it

Comment: @adiga I tried using the same binding in Edit, `Name: self.Name()` but it just refreshes the table and does not get the edited value back ?

Comment: I believe that for the beginning you should replace both `<input type="submit" ... />` with `<input type="button" ... />` to avoid unpredictable interfering between browser’s default reaction on “submit” and `onClick` handler...

Comment: @OleksandrTyshchenko that did not make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error, it says the self.Name is not function and you are calling it in your Add function like this : `self.Name()` instead try `self.Name`